# Blocking xlarge screens android

Tags: android, screen, tablet

I have uploaded a apk file to the market which supports 1.6+. I noticed that this api lvl doesnt support to block xlarge screens from the manifest. If i upload 2 apk files to the market with one 1.6+ and one 2.3 or 3.0 that blocks xlarge screens, will the xlarge screens be blocked then. Or will they choose the 1.6+ version instead the 2.3/3.0 version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well X-Large screens are available since API 10, So you can block them by regulate `android:maxSdkVersion="9"` method on your `AndroidManifest`.